# Issues with a PHP program that Prints out "&" until the numbers equal "i"

Tags: php, function, printing, url-rewriting

Here's how it's written, I'm having issues figuring out how to rewrite it.

```
public function broken(int x) {
    while(i < x) {
        i = 1;
        print("&");
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take `i = 1;` out of the loop. You're setting it back to 1 each time.

Comment: Why are the variables missing `$`, if PHP?

Answer (score 0):

¿Are you sure this is PHP?
If so, your function should be written like this:

```
public function broken(int $x) {
    //$i goes out of the while loop, otherwise your are constatnly reseting
    //it to 1, making the loop infinite.
    $i = 1;

    while($i < $x) {
        echo("&");
        i++;
    }
}
```